# Presentation tool/app: Audience participation : Poll/Wordcloud with smartphone

Tags: presentation, app

Is there a free or inexpensive app that facilitates audience-participation during in-person presentations or classrooms?

A few years ago I have been to a presentation where the presenter showed an short URL or a QR Code on the screen, and then asked the audience to get out their smartphones, and open the URL, which led to a web page.

The audience's task was to type in something (Answer to Q "What is the benefit you expect from his event?"), and immediately there appeared a dynamic wordcloud on the screen. I think later(in the same presentation) there where also some simple polls with yes/no questions or similar.

Is there an app that does approximately this? (At that event they said their app was custom programmed).

Only a smartphone should be required, no clickers / remote controls or any extra hardware.